# PIP install and Python path

Tags: python, macos, installation, pip

I am using pip install on a mac to get my python requirements for a django website.

I got pip from MacPorts

```
port install pip-2.7
```

Now the problem is the pip installs the packages in a location which is not in my python sys.path.

I just copied this bogus location

```
/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/)
```

to a location present in my sys.path

```
/Library/Python/2.7/)
```

Of course this worked ok, but I will use pip in the future so I need a persistent solution.

The question is how can I alter my sys.path to recognize that crap location or how do I tell pip to install dependencies somewhere else ?

Comment: virtualenv obviates this kind of problem. Aren't you using virtualenv?

Comment: Cross site duplicate, http://superuser.com/q/420908/86903.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

After a few attempts, setting the PYTHONPATH environmental var worked.

Best way to achieve this is to add the following to the ~/.bash_profile:

```
export PYTHONPATH=<bogus path here>
```

Don't forget to open a new terminal after changing.

Comment: ... or use `source ~/.bashrc` in the same terminal