# Python import error :No module named Fabric.api?

Tags: python, fabric, importerror

I am getting the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "drayd.py", line 2, in <module>
    from fabric.api import *
**ImportError: No module named fabric.api**
```

I am running my program using:

```
python drayd.py
```

These are my imports:

```
import os,pprint
from fabric.api import *
import time
import argparse
import ConfigParser
```

I don't have a file named fabric as other answers suggested. I installed fabric using pip but it still doesn't work, any suggestions?
I am using the OSX Terminal.

NOTE: I realized the fabric I installed is not linked to python installation ie it does not recognize that fabric is installed by pip.
I am using the python version 2.7 default by osx.
How do I link fabric installation to python?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer to my question is right here :

**[PIP install and Python path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10461590/pip-install-and-python-path)**

I had to add the location of my packages( which were installing not in the sys.path) so I had to add them manually
Use `pip show` to find location of the packages and add them to `.bash_profile`
as @Javier Buzzi said I will take the advice and also run my python code from virtualenv.

Answer (score 24):

After doing some research I found out that when you `pip install fabric`, it installs fabric v2. This version [introduced](https://www.fabfile.org/upgrading.html) "a near-total reimplementation & reorganization of the software". Your code was written for fabric v1, and needs to be rewritten to be compatible with fabric v2.

### Python 2.7

Per Robert Lujo's answer, you can downgrade fabric to v1.

```
pip install 'fabric<2.0'
```

### Python 3

Fabric v1 isn't compatible with Python 3, so you can instead install a fork called [fabric3](https://pypi.org/project/Fabric3/).

```
pip uninstall fabric
pip install fabric3
```

Note that the fabric3 fork has been [deprecated](https://github.com/mathiasertl/fabric/) by the maintainer, so you should consider making the code updates required to [upgrade](https://www.fabfile.org/upgrading.html) to fabric v2.

Comment: Wow, how did you find it out that fabric is fabric2 and not compatible?

Comment: Hey @Timo what you can do to check any version of any installation / library is - pip show fabric and it'll show you the current version pip has installed for it.

Answer (score 9):

Similar issue happens if you have fabfile.py based on older fabric versions, i.e. 1.x. Currently fabric latest version is 2.x which [is not backward compatible](http://www.fabfile.org/upgrading.html#upgrading):

> As of the 2.0 release line, Fabric 2 is not at 100% feature parity
>   with 1.x! Some features have been explicitly dropped, but others
>   simply have not been ported over yet,

[Regarding fabric.api](http://www.fabfile.org/upgrading.html#api-organization) - it does not exist any more:

> - Import everything via fabric.api
> - Removed
> - All useful imports are now available at the top level, e.g. from fabric import Connection.

It is recommended to upgrade fabfile.py from 1.x to 2.x [for lot of reasons](http://www.fabfile.org/upgrading.html#why-upgrade) (*e.g. Python 3 compatibility - specifically, we now support 2.7 and 3.4+*), but if you still don't want to upgrade, you could uninstall 2.x and [install 1.x](http://www.fabfile.org/installing-1.x.html), e.g.

```
pip uninstall fabric
pip install 'fabric<2.0'
```

Answer (score 1):

You're going to have to be more explicit. I created a new `virtualenv`, installed `fabric` and everything is fine. You need to paste more source or more information about your environment.

```
$ cd /tmp
$ virtualenv test && source test/bin/activate
$ pip install fabric
...
Successfully installed fabric-1.10.2
$ python
>>> from fabric.api import *
>>>
```

lets see what you have:

```
$ python
>>> import pkgutil
>>> [name for _, name, _ in pkgutil.iter_modules()]
... paste THIS output somewhere ...
```

PS. it's really good to do all your tests/projects inside a virtualenv/pyenv so that you never have conflicts with current/future projects.

Comment: I am new to fabric and python, what other information should I post?

Comment: I have to run my python code on a remote server from my computer, I have the python 2.7 installed on my computer, I am using the terminal

Comment: I did pip install fabric and it was fine, when I run fab it says :

Fatal error: Couldn't find any fabfiles!

Remember that -f can be used to specify fabfile path, and use -h for help.

Aborting.

Comment: Are you running your file directly or are you using `fab` ? if you want yo do `$ fab <name of operation>` you MUST have a fabfile.py. And i mean paste the whole source. and how you're running it.

PLEASE make sure you remove any secrets /passwords/keys from source.

Comment: No, I have a script that imports the library, I used it to do some operations on the server, but its a part of a python script called dryad.py.

Comment: I run my file as I wrote above python dryad.py

Comment: I cant paste the code here, the formatting gets all messed up. Look at the part "lets see what you have"

Comment: It gives all the packages installed, and fabric is not present there! How do I include it there?

Comment: Right thats what i feared. You need to look at where you installed it. This is why virtualenv is so important -- saves you from pulling your hair out. You can do this: `python -c "import sys; print sys.path"` and make sure where ever `fabric` is -- is in that list. you can also add it 'sys.path.append("<path here>")'

Comment: Frankly. I would add a `virtualenv` and run your code in there. You can alway be sure that all your modules will be in the pip you installed it in.

Answer (score 0):

Solved the error by switching from python3.9 to python3.7

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33446552)