# Python - fabric module missing all of a sudden

Tags: python, linux, tkinter, fabric, conda

i am new to python and i am experimenting with fabric and matplotlib modules.
i have created a virtual Env with conda and am writing programs and executing inside the virtual Env.

i have written a script that uses fabric.api( a fabfile.py). I am importing this fabfile into another python script (Window.py) and using the definition in fabfile in Window.py. Everything is working fine and i am happy.

Now i wanted to plot graphs on some data i extracted using Fabric. so i made a research and found matplotlib was apt for my purpose . i installed this module from conda inside the virtual Env. so to my surprise once i installed this and ran my Window.py, i get this below shown Error !

```
**Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Window.py", line 9, in <module>
    from fabfile import *
  File "F:\home\WorkSpace\FIrstPyProject\TestModules\fabfile.py", line 2, in <module>
    from fabric.api import *
ImportError: No module named fabric.api**
```

here is my code samples,

Fabfile.py

```
from fabric.api import *

import sys
def hello():
    print "hello world"

def connect(commandInput):
    print "starting to connect"
    env.host_string = 'nms@10.0.0.70'
    env.password = "nms"
    with hide('output','running'):
        p=run(commandInput)
        return p
```

Window.py

```
import Tkinter as tk
import csv
import MasterWindow
from fabfile import *
import time
from fabric.api import *

LARGE_FONT= ("Verdana", 12)
env.host_string = 'nms@10.0.0.70'
env.password = "nms"

class StartPage(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self,parent)      
        label = tk.Label(self, text="Graphy-Home", font=LARGE_FONT)     
        label.pack(pady=10,padx=10)     
        Command = tk.Label(self, text="Enter Command")      
        pickCommand = tk.Entry(self)        
        pickCommand.pack(pady=10)           
        Command.pack()  
        button1 = tk.Button(self, text="Submit Command", command=lambda: submit())      
        button1.pack()  

    def submit(ItrCnt=0,sleepTime=3):
        while (ItrCnt < 10):
            print (pickCommand.get())
            cmd=pickCommand.get()
            ItrCnt=ItrCnt+1
            time.sleep(sleepTime)
            p=connect(cmd)              
            print(p.stdout)
```

when i run the defs inside fabfile in the below shown way, things are fine,

```
fab -a connect
```

but when i am calling the Connect() from Window.py things are not working like before the installation of matplotlib

i see a question most similar to the one i asked here in this link below

[Python import error :No module named Fabric.api?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33148831/python-import-error-no-module-named-fabric-api)

i dint get much help from the accepted answer here as i don't want to use PIP now as there is some dependency on my windows with PIP which is not getting resolved. i want to use conda itself. is there anyway i can get around this problem? thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would try first to import only the functions needed from the modules, to avoid problems with namespace.

In your fabfile:

```
from fabric.api import env,hide,run

import sys
def hello():
    print "hello world"

def connect(commandInput):
    print "starting to connect"
    env.host_string = 'nms@10.0.0.70'
    env.password = "nms"
    with hide('output','running'):
        p=run(commandInput)
        return p
```

And in your Windows.py:

```
import Tkinter as tk
import csv
import MasterWindow
from fabfile import connect
import time
from fabric.api import env

LARGE_FONT= ("Verdana", 12)
env.host_string = 'nms@10.0.0.70'
env.password = "nms"

class StartPage(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self,parent)      
        label = tk.Label(self, text="Graphy-Home", font=LARGE_FONT)     
        label.pack(pady=10,padx=10)     
        Command = tk.Label(self, text="Enter Command")      
        pickCommand = tk.Entry(self)        
        pickCommand.pack(pady=10)           
        Command.pack()  
        button1 = tk.Button(self, text="Submit Command", command=lambda: submit())      
        button1.pack()  

    def submit(ItrCnt=0,sleepTime=3):
        while (ItrCnt < 10):
            print (pickCommand.get())
            cmd=pickCommand.get()
            ItrCnt=ItrCnt+1
            time.sleep(sleepTime)
            p=connect(cmd)              
            print(p.stdout)
```

Also, be sure that the `PYTHONPATH` is the same when running fabfile and Window.py, as the `PYTHONPATH` is where Python will look for modules to load. To check it, put this line at the begining of your files:

```
import sys
print("PYTHONPATH:{0}".format(sys.path))
```

Comment: yes ! this worked mate! but do you mind explaining why this worked and wats wrong in importing all the modules with * in the import statement?

Comment: It happens when functions that have the same name in different modules are imported with *. If you import just the functions you need, it's less probably that names collide. Another option is to import just the module, so the functions will have the name module.function(), and that will be unique.